# Visual Studio 2010 UnhandledException, ThreadException error handling?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, error-handling

In my code I had an error that was catched by following exceptions while program was running. However when I was running program in Visual Studio when the error was happening application was simply exiting without any error (other errors usually bring me to the problematic line).

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) {
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += currentDomainUnhandledException;
    Application.ThreadException += applicationThreadException;
}
```

Of course if i remove the `if` i get this exception handling done by my methods which simply uses `MessageBox` to show the error. Is there a way to force Visual Studio to catch this error like it catches other types of errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by using Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox.  That makes the debugger stop on the "first chance".  At the point the exception is thrown.  You typically want to do this:

```
        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
            // Subscribe the events
            //...
        }
```

Note that this already works that way for Application.ThreadException, Winforms already avoids catching exceptions if it sees a debugger.  For the exact same reason.

Comment: Where can i find this checkbox?

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, it brings up a dialog box.

Comment: Should I enable every single exception to be thrown ? Or are there particular ones I should have enabled?